# How to update N-Dimension numpy array from one process to another process in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have two numpy arrays.

```
fullsize_batch1=np.zeros((BATCHSIZE, ORGHEIGHT, ORGWIDTH, CHANNEL), dtype=np.uint8)
fullsize_batch2=np.zeros((BATCHSIZE, ORGHEIGHT, ORGWIDTH, CHANNEL), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Two processes are running with two while loops.

One is `While loop in main` and another one is `While loop in BatchProcessing mentod`.

`fullsize_batch1` and `fullsize_batch2` are directly accessed in main While loop and I like to pass `fullsize_batch1` and `fullsize_batch2` to `BatchProcessing` during both `While loops are running`.

multiprocessing.Array is used to share between processes. But array is passed at time when processes is started and not at the middle of running. For me , I like to `update data regularly from main while loop` to `BatchProcessing while loop.`

How can I update regularly and fastly?